# Склонение фамилии Койда

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

На работе при заполнении документации просклоняла фамилию **Койда** в родительном падеже с окончанием ***-ы***. На следующий день получила массу негатива со стороны ее владелицы. Она утверждала, что ее фамилия не склоняется.
Проштудировала правила русского языка: вроде бы склоняется.
Хотелось бы подтверждения со стороны профессионалов.

Comment: Профессионалов-то тут особо и нету... Но вы всё сделали правильно. Все фамилии на -а склоняются (кроме французских, но это отдельный разговор). Здесь уже не один десяток подобных вопросов был - поищите. Или с "Грамоты". http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_8_familii/

Answer (score 1):

Из "Справочника по правописанию и литературной правке"<sup>1</sup> Розенталя:

> Из фамилий на ударяемые *-а* склоняются только славянские.
>
> Нерусские фамилии на неударяемые *-а*, *-я* (в основном славянские и романские) склоняются. Исключение составляют фамилии на *-а*, *-я* с предшествующим гласным *-и*. Не склоняются также финские фамилии на -а.

То есть склоняемость зависит от того, считаем мы фамилию финской или нет. Этот вопрос стоит задать экспертам по генеалогии.

**Upd.:** Вижу, что высказываются сомнения не только в том, важно ли то, что фамилия финская (в том числе, почему-то под сомнение было поставлено наличие такого указания у Розенталя), но и в самой возможности финского происхождения фамилии *Койда*. Ещё раз повторюсь, что второй вопрос следует задать специалистам по генеалогии: ответы могут быть отличны для того или иного человека.

Касательно того, какая вообще разница финская это фамилия или нет, я приведу [ссылку](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=265608) на всю ту же Грамоту<sup>2</sup>, раз решения их бюро в таком почете. Из ответа к "вопросу № 265608" (выделение жирным моё):

> У лингвистов тоже война :) Разнятся рекомендации, приведенные в лингвистических источниках.
>
> (...)
>
> Так, в «Справочнике по русскому языку: правописание, произношение, литературное редактирование» **Д. Э. Розенталя**, Е. В. Джанджаковой, Н. П. Кабановой (М., 2010) содержится прямое указание: **не склоняются финские фамилии на -а**.
>
> (...)
>
> Подробные правила склонения имен и фамилий приведены во вступительной статье в словаре Ф. Л. Агеенко «Собственные имена в русском языке». Здесь читаем: «**Финские имена и фамилии, оканчивающиеся на -а неударное, преимущественно не склоняются**, например: ПЕККАЛА Mayно, нескл.».
>
> (...)
>
> По-видимому, окончательное решение о склонении / несклонении финской фамилии на -а, -я следует оставить за носителем фамилии. Если речь идет о фамилии известного человека (Пеккала, например), следует руководствоваться словарными рекомендациями. Если же словарной фиксации нет, а мнение носителя фамилии узнать невозможно, то **финские фамилии на -а, -я лучше не склонять**.
>
> **Ответы, в которых однозначно рекомендовалось склонять финские фамилии, исправлены.**

Очевидно, что ответы были исправлены не все.

Тем не менее, если верить всё той же Грамоте, то становится КРАЙНЕ важно финская это фамилия или нет.

Я соглашусь, что мой оригинальный ответ был несколько поспешен, однако я, тем не менее, приведу следующую аргументацию, которая может быть и не относится к тематике русского языка, но интересна в контексте как данного вопроса, так и истории русского языка и культуры (а также языков и культур, вошедших в них).

Итак, касательно топонимики реки *Койда*. Т.А. Бернштам в "Поморы. Формирование группы и система хозяйства"<sup>3</sup> указывает, что р. Койда в Архангельской области является, скорее всего, вторичным топонимом:

> Впервые название Койда (река) появляется на карте, опубликованной в 1745 г. и в документе конца  XVIII в., отражающем спор малонемнюжских и куйских крестьян за р. Койду. Возможно, что, несмотря на более давнее пребывание в этих местах малонемнюжских крестьян, название Койда было принесено двинянами с нижней Двины, где в конце XVI—начале XVII в. существовала Койдокурская волость.

Важно понимать, что упомянутые Койдокурья в том или ином виде существовали едва ли не с XV века. Так, в сборнике "Акты социально-экономической истории Севера России конца XV - XVI в. Акты Соловецкого монастыря, 1479-1571 гг." (составитель И.З. Либерзон, 1988) <sup>4</sup> присутствует документ №148 от 1 августа 1548 года: "Закладная Павла Коровая<sup>а</sup> и Петра Григорьевых детей Поливщицыных Соловецкому монастырю на долю варницы в Солокурье". В нем, в качестве одного из свидетелей, подписался "Тимофей Селивестров ис Койдокурьи" (Sic).

В частности, особый интерес в данном вопросе представляет легенда основания Койдокурьи, дошедшая до наших дней благодаря исследователям фольклора. Из "Заволоцкая чудь" (составитель П.С. Ефименко, 1869)<sup>5</sup>:

> Село Койдокурья, Архангельскаго уѣзда, какъ говорятъ крестьяне, получило свое названіе отъ перваго поселившагося въ тамошмей мѣстности Чудина, по прозванію Койда, или Койка. Откуда собственно пришелъ Койда, и когда поселился—преданіе умалчиваетъ;

*Чудь*, северные народы, преимущественно прибалты и финны. Район вокруг Северной Двины, о котором идет речь, является частью исторической территории Биармии, населенной незадолго до основания Койдокурья (возможно, вплоть до XIII в.) ныне утерянным народом Биармцев.

Из "Fibula, Fabula, Fact: The Viking Age in Finland" (Frog J. A., Tolley C., 2014, перевод мой)<sup>6</sup>:

> Идентификация людей Белого моря, называемых "Биармцы" в древнескандинавских и древнеанглийских источниках, как говорящих на прибалтийско-финском языке подерживала образ финских языков, преобладающих на непрерывном континууме по всей "Финляндии". Однако, топонимические признаки противоречат этой картине и предполагают, что Биармцы, возможно совсем не были северно-финской группой: возможно, они были другой (южно-финской или глубинно-финской) лингвокультурной группой (или несколькими группами), принимающей участие в переселениях народов, которые стимулировались в этой части мира в то время. Преобладание финского и карельского в этих регионах в последующие периоды во многом является результатом процессов, следовавших за Эпохой Викингов. Однако Эпоха Викингов — особенно как несколько более гибкий период 750–1250 г. — кажется, была неотъемлимой фазой этого процесса.

Таким образом, *чудина* Койда, который поселился в Койдокурье, вполне мог говорить либо на самом финском, либо на родственном ему языке. Поэтому нельзя просто так исключать возможность финского происхождения слова Койда.

В связи с чем я напоследок ещё раз повторюсь: вопрос о том, происходит ли фамилия Койда из финской традиции стоит задать профессиональному генеалогу. Не просто ономасту, а именно генеалогу, который смог бы проследить откуда происходит фамилия конкретного человека.

P.S. Ну и в конце концов, двадцать первый век на дворе, люди вправе сами решать какие правила применяются к их именам. Иначе это, получается, не их имена, а общественные. Тогда зачем они вообще им нужны.

---

1. Розенталь Д. Э. Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке: Для работников печати. — 5-е изд., испр. — М.: Книга, 1989.
2. Грамота. Вопрос № 265608. [Онлайн] http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=265608
3. Бернштам, Т. А. Поморы.Формирование группы и система хозяйства. — АН СССР, Ин-т этнографии им. Н. Н. Миклухо-Маклая. — Ленинград: Наука, 1978.
4. Акты социально-экономической истории Севера России конца XV–XVI вв.; Акты Соловецкого монастыря, 1479–1571. Сост И. З. Либерзон. — Ленинград: Наука, 1988.
5. Заволоцкая чудь. Составитель П. С. Ефименко. — Архангельск, Губернская типография, 1869.
6. Frog J. A., Tolley C. Fibula, Fabula, Fact: The Viking Age in Finland. – Finnish Literature Society/SKS, 2014.

Comment: Ссылочку дайте, плз. на Розенталя.

Comment: Год какой? ПС, Вот не надо только про мою ссылку. По моей ссылке русским языком - "(хотя в ряде источников рекомендуется склонять и их)". При этом ссылки на Р. там нет.

Comment: Поддержал ответ, но во всех подобных случаях я предупреждаю, что вопрос может касаться не только ономастики, но и вопросов кадрового делопроизводства, например. И если у человека во всех документах фамилия никогда не склонялась, а очередной кадровик начнёт её склонять, я не знаю, как это может аукнуться в дальнейшем для человека.

Answer (score 1):

*Фамиля **Койда** склоняется.*
Независимо от происхождения, **-а** в ней не может быть ударяемым, да и происхождение её, очевидно, не финское.

(+) ===
Не люблю отвечать на вопрос, который неоднократно уже отвечен. Но тут ответ дали, с которым я просто не могу согласиться ни по сути, ни по логике.

Во-первых, **-а** в фамилии Койда не может быть ударяемая.
Во-вторых, фамилия, вероятнее всего, южнорусская. Об этом говорит и её распространенность. При этом происхождение (безсуффиксальное) крайне маловероятно — эта версия проводится в псевдосправочниках "Происхождение фамилии", где все сведения вымышлены "от и до".

И комментарий "Справки"

Действительно, в «Справочнике по правописанию и литературной правке» Д. Э. Розенталя приведена следующая рекомендация: из фамилий на ударяемые **-а** склоняются только славянские. Однако специалисты по ономастике (т. е. лингвисты, углубленно изучающие особенности образования и функционирования в речи имен, отчеств, фамилий) предписывают склонять все фамилии, оканчивающиеся на ударное **-а**, оставляя несклоняемыми только фамилии французского происхождения (типа Дюма). ***Такая рекомендация приведена в «Словаре русских личных имен» А. В. Суперанской, в исследовании Л. П. Калакуцкой «Фамилии. Имена. Отчества. Написание и склонение» и др.*** На наш взгляд, фамилию Ракша следует склонять.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=251510+%09+
(курсив мой — b-s)

(++) =====

[Простите, писал наспех, отредактирую при первой возможности, если добрые люди не помогут.]

Но вот ссылку одну дам. Этот архив куда более достоверен, чем все "уфологи", заверяющие в финском происхождении.

https://rosgenea.ru/familiya/kojda

Среди прочих, очевидно, украинских носителей фамилии упоминается:
***Койда Гаврыло (1756) в 1756 казак Конелевского куреня Войска Запорожского по реестру 1756 г.***
Тоже финн?